# OnBackPressedCallback not called - Activitiy is terminated immediately

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

**Hello,**

adding `OnBackPressedDispatcher` and `OnBackPressedCallback` in my MainActivity cause `onBackPressed`was deprecated.

**old usage:**

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Display alert message when back button has been pressed
    alertDialogShow();
}
```

**New usage:**
put it in my initialize listener call in `MainActivity` `onCreate()` - initListeners()

```
    onBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            //Display alert message when back button has been pressed
            alertDialogShow();
        }
    };

    onBackPressedDispatcher = new OnBackPressedDispatcher();
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this,onBackPressedCallback);
```

but the method alterDialogShow() is never called and the activity is terminated immediately.
How can I solve this.

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: When the activity is terminated is there any errors?.

Comment: no, no errors were shown

Comment: okay, what you are trying to do is when the user press the back button you want to show a alert dialog to confirm that action. right ?

Comment: yes, thats what should happen and worked on the old way

Comment: try to have the alert dialog implemented inside the handleOnBackPressed()

Comment: I find, that handleOnBackPressed() is not called...but the activity is shut down

Comment: Please expand on is not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `OnBackPressedDispatcher` but you must use the Activity's  `OnBackPressedDispatcher` and add your callback to it:

```
//onBackPressedDispatcher = new OnBackPressedDispatcher();
onBackPressedDispatcher = getOnBackPressedDispatcher();

onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on my comment above. this is one way to do it.

```
   OnBackPressedCallback onBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Create an AlertDialog to confirm the action
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Confirm Action")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Perform the desired action when the user confirms
                        // For example, you can call super.onBackPressed() to go back
                        super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing or handle the cancel action here
                    }
                })
                .show();
        }
    };

    // Add the callback to the back stack
    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback);
}
```